# How Do I Find the Largest Number in a 3D Array?

Tags: javascript

**How do I find the largest number in this three Dimensional Array?**  `I am looking to return ninety from this function.` ** Documentation is sparse I've been looking all day.**

````
          ```
          let array = [17,[83,49],[43,[90],[62]]];
          Array.max = function(array) {`
          console.log(Math.max.apply(Math,array));}
          ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const array = [17, [83, 49], [43, [90], [62]]];

Array.prototype.max = function () {
  return Math.max(...this.flat(Infinity));
}

console.log(array.max()); // 90
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to flat array first

```js
let array = [17,[83,49],[43,[90],[62]]];
let arr = array.flat(2);
let max = Math.max(...arr);
console.log(max);
```